# Nested for loops to iterate through the same input file in python

Tags: python

I have below a simplified version of the code that I'm running:

```
def method():

    inputFile = open(current_file, 'r')
    readPos = 1

    for i in inputFile:
        if readPos == 1:
            readPos += 1
        elif readPos == 2:
            readPos += 1

            linePos = 1

            for x in inputFile:
                print x,
                if linePos == 1:
                    linePos += 1
                elif linePos == 2:
                    linePos += 1
                elif linePos == 3:
                    linePos = 1
        elif readPos == 3:
            readPos = 1
```

Without the details, I am trying to use the first `for-loop` to move line by line through a file, then each time I reach lines 2,5,8... I would like to use the second `for-loop` to move line by line through the same file again.

The problem I'm having is that where I am showing `print x,` to me it seems that the first time this line is reached `x` should be equal to the first line of the file, but it is actually equal to the 3rd line of the file, and I don't understand why that is, and don't know how to make that second loop start at the first line of the file. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you read the whole file into a string and call `splitlines()`?  `inputFile = open(blob, 'r')`, `data = inputFile.read()', `lines = data.splitlines()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
def method():
    with open(current_file, 'r') as inputFile:
        lines = inputFile.read().splitlines()
    for li in lines:
        # Do something
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but I don't understand why I am able to iterate through the same list two separate times but not through the same file?

Comment: Once you iterate to the end of the file there isn't anything left to read.  You could probably use `inputFile.seek(0)` to restart your file pointer at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you could try something like this

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open("file.txt")] #read file into a list

for index,each in enumerate(line):
    if index in [2,5,8]:
        for j in line:
            print j #will print entire list 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You only create a single iterator with the open statement. Both loops are drawing water from the same well -- not two different wells. If you want to do the sort of thing you are trying to do, read the lines into a list and have two loops access elements from the same list by indices.

Answer (score 1):

Just after your "elif readPos == 2:" line you iterate the readPos var.

If you move that iteration after the second for loop, that should solve it.